# Control guided access from application

Tags: objective-c

We have an app with an assessment module where we take a objective type test. We don't want that user will switch between apps to cheat. Currently we are rejecting test in case when application goes to background.

**In iOS 6 Apple introduced a new feature called Guided Access and I am wounding if we can control it by an Objective C code snippet.**

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same situation recently. There does'nt seem to be any way to enable or trigger guided access from objective c code.
However you can check from with in objective c whether guided access is enabled or not using
    UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()

It returns YES if guided access is enabled.
So you can allow the user to give the test **only** when guided access is enabled.

If you want to know when guided access is enabled or disabled, you've got to setup something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(guidedAccessChanged) name:UIAccessibilityGuidedAccessStatusDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

You can read more about it here:

[UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled)

[UIAccessibilityGuidedAccessStatusDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008786-CH1-SW50)